# ZSH mapfile, how can I get the bash behaviour?

Tags: bash, shell-script, zsh

Both bash and zsh support reading a file into an array, I'm used to the bash's way and am appalled by the zsh's behaviour: zsh starts the array from index 1!  That's not the unix way.

Here is an example, let's create a file:

```
echo yay1 >> pp
echo yay2 >> pp
echo yay3 >> pp
```

And use the bash `mapfile` (`-t` prevents the newlines to be sucked into the array elements):

```
[~]$ mapfile -t arr < pp
[~]$ echo "${arr[0]}"
yay1
[~]$ echo "${arr[1]}"
yay2
[~]$ echo "${arr[2]}"
yay3
```

Cool, that's what I'm used to.  Now let's try zsh (we need to load the module):

```
% zmodload zsh/mapfile                     
% arr=("${(f@)mapfile[pp]}")
% echo "${arr[0]}"          

% echo "${arr[1]}"
yay1
% echo "${arr[2]}"
yay2
% echo "${arr[3]}"
yay3
```

Ooops, that's not the unix way of indexing things.

How can I make the zsh's mapfile to start the array from index 0?

Comment: @jasonwryan - Nice, so it is bash (or better, Korn's) behaviour that's inconsistent.  'tis a dupe alright.  The actual "solution" is to start using `i-1` in bash.  Thanks

Comment: There is the option of `setopt -o KSH_ZERO_SUBSCRIPT` or the more coarse `setopt -o KSH_ARRAYS`. Both will allow the use of zero array, but the seconds has some other (additional) consequences.

Comment: @sorontar - God bless I have not tried yet rewriting the script that i'm moving to zsh (don't ask why, it is just a horrible violation of "if it ain't broke don't fix").  That's a lot easier.  Thanks